What was the exact timespan and period of the events and situation encapsulated in “Civil War?”
Alex Garland has been (purposefully) vague about timeline specifics of the film, Civil War (2024). But are there in-film clues as to how the situation in the U.S. degraded seemingly so quickly?
I picked up some clues in a single theater viewing:

The President has apparently not been seen in public for about 14 months.
Lee Smith is a hardened conflict photographer in her 40s.
Jessie is 20-something who tags along.
Lee talks a lot about her career beginnings at Jessie’s age with Joel.
There is a scene at a “Christmas Village” but it is clearly springtime in the film.
There is a scene at a hotel that is clearly functional but suffers from occasional brownouts.
There is clearly a highly fortified area that was built around the White House.

While things have clearly gone to hell pretty much everywhere, things are not utterly completely broken down. But it’s odd? A refugee camp on a football field with darkened homes clear see from behind. It seems messy, but somewhat “freshly” messy.
So, what was the exact timespan and period of the events and situation encapsulated in the “Civil War?”
Can anything be gleaned from the subtle clues in the film despite Alex Garland’s purposefully vagueness?
Seems to me that this film was set in the 14 months since the start of the President’s latest term. No election was ever mentioned in the film, but boy howdy! Are people clearly up in (literal) arms.
